# Why does the code crash? (in CPP)

Tags: c++, arrays

The following code crashes:

```
int main()
{
  int n, arr[n];
  cin>>n;      
}
```

The following code works fine

```
int main()
{
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  int arr[n];
}
```

Comment: Do you expect `arr` to change size if you were do add another `cin>>n;`

Comment: Neither of those are valid C++.

Comment: in the first example `n` has some garbage value. Try printing it to see what it is.

Comment: What do you expect `int n, arr[n];` to do? In fact according to the standard you can't use a variable for the size of an array at all

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) to begin with.

Comment: When the program reaches `int arr[n];`, it sets the array size to the value of `n`. When you change `n` later, it doesn't affect the array in any way.

Answer (score 12):

In the first case, `arr[n];` is reading an *uninitialised* `n`, the behaviour of which is *undefined*

Note that in C++, Variable Length Arrays are a compiler extension anyway.

Use a `std::vector` (or a `std::array` if you have a good reason to; you probably don't) for portable C++.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an array without giving size of array.

```
int n, arr[n];
```

Here, `n` is not initialised.

Comment: In C++, an array size must be a compile-time constant, which means there's no question about it being initialized.